# Positioning a view on top of a tableview using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a tableview in my storyboard that has its class set to my `UITableView` subclass which is named `SPSExplanationTableView`. There are no constraints set on this tableview in Interface Builder.

I am trying to programmatically create a `UIView` that displays in front of the tableview—[which I know how to do](https://sideprojectsoftware.com/blog/2014/08/10/explanation-table-view.html) (blog post link)—but that is sized and positioned using Auto Layout. This is my code:

```
#import "SPSExplanationTableView.h"

@interface SPSExplanationTableView()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *explanationView;

@end

@implementation SPSExplanationTableView

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.explanationView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.explanationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.explanationView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    [self addSubview:self.explanationView];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:self.explanationView];

NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.explanationView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:nil
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                   multiplier:1.0f constant:150.0f];
[self.explanationView addConstraint:heightConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.explanationView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                      toItem:nil
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                  multiplier:1.0f constant:200.0f];
[self.explanationView addConstraint:widthConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.explanationView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:self
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
[self addConstraint:topConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.explanationView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:self
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                 multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
[self addConstraint:leftConstraint];

@end
```

When I run the app it crashes with the following assertion failure:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[SPSExplanationTableView layoutSublayersOfLayer:],
/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UIView.m:8794
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still
required after executing -layoutSubviews. SPSExplanationTableView's
implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
```

Taking the message literally and overriding `layoutSubviews` has no effect i.e. I still get the same crash.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

What's the correct way to implement what I'm trying to achieve?

---

For Aubada Taljo, here's the tableview in Interface Builder:

[image]

---

**Update:** I solved this myself in the end by not using Auto Layout! I overrode the layoutSubviews method in my SPSExplanationTableView class and set the center property of the explanationView to the centre of self's bounds, with some slight adjustments to the y-axis position to make it look how I wanted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is crashing because UITableViews are not designed to do this. A UITableView is only concerned about its cells, the headers, maybe its background, and it has logic for this that doesn't use autolayout. So it will crash if you try to involve it in any constraints calculation between it and any subviews, e.g. this will also crash if you add a constraint between the cell and the table.

What I suggest you do is to add a superview that will contain both your table and the view that you want to overlay:

```
SuperviewWithConstraints
    |
    |-- YourTableViewWithConstraintsRelativeToSuperview
    |
    |-- YourOverlayWithConstraintsRelativeToSuperview
```

And set up the constraints there. Then make that superview as your view controller's view. You will have to move away from using the UITableViewController as the controlling class, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you would take my advice and make your life easier, simply go to your storyboard in Interface Builder and set the correct constraints on the your table view, now go back to the code editor and in the UIViewController that owns your table view, write the view creation code in viewDidLoad e.g.

```
UIView* someView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubView someView];
```

I guess this should be more than enough to solve your issue, now if you face any problems, move your code to viewDidLayoutSubViews in the UIViewController

Please tell me if you need more details but I use this way of creating dynamic controls all the time.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how I can set the correct constraints on the tableview in Interface Builder because the child view doesn't exist there. Also, I don't particularly want to clutter up my view controller with view creation code. It feels like I should be able to use a self-contained tableview class for this.

Comment: The key is that you don't have to set the correct constraints for the child view (someView), you just set the correct ones for the table view in Interface Builder and the above code shall do the rest.

Also it's not good at all to add the view as a child of the UITableView cause it wasn't designed for that, so the above code shall show you what you want

Comment: So what would the correct constraints for the tableview be?

Comment: Would you show me a screenshot of the view controller in your interface builder (the one that contains the uitableview)

Comment: I've edited my question to include a screenshot as requested. The view controller is a UITableViewController subclass.